# How to paginate with apache kafka messages

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

A pagination system is done with total records and specify offset to start paginate.

How can I get total records and offset in kafka from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't paginate. A topic is a sequential log of events.

However, your consumer group has an initial or stored offset, and on the next poll, will read up to `max.poll.records` for the next "page" after that offset.

If you want to count the number of records in a non compacted topic, you can use `GetOffsetShell` tool to query the first and last offset, then subtract the difference. For a compacted topic, there are gaps in those numbers and the only reasonable way to count records is to consume the entire topic